# How to apply input which has type number in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have made web apps using by Nuxt.js.
I'm trying to apply for validation which excludes negative values and decimal points to all input tag(20~30) in same vue component.
I think the way of injecting the validation rules to input tag on vue life-cycle mounted events goning to be success, but nothing change input tag.

```
<template>
・・・・・・・
<input
    type="number"
    style="width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; text-align: right"
     v-model="item"
        />
・・・・・・・
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'nuxt-property-decorator'
@Component({})
export default class extends Vue {
   onNumbers = (val: any) => {
    return val.replace(/\D/g, '')
  }

  mounted() {
    document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach((item) => {
      item.addEventListener('input', (val) => {
        this.onNumbers(val)
      })
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

Does anyone advise me?

Comment: if you set the `min` property of the input tag to `0` first condition is met but i didn't understand second condition which is `decimal points to all input tag(20~30)`. please bring an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `input`-tag set following properties to `min="0"` and `step="1"` and it should work.

```
<input
    type="number"
    min="0"
    step="1"
    style="width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; text-align: right"
    v-model="item"
/>
```